# click handler issue on changePage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm doing a simple page transition with `changePage` when "click" triggered but after first transition, binding detaches. I've tried `reloadPage` but same.

Sample code:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#index", function () {
    $("#button").live("click", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("../s/", {
            reloadPage: true
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Note: both page ids are "index".

Comment: You don't need "return false"

Comment: didn't see any error. tried all possibilities but not worked :(

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#index", function () {
    $("#button").live("click", function () {
        $(location).attr('href',"../s/");       
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. Let me know about your results.